# Listening to oracle DBMS_ALERT in Delphi

Tags: oracle, delphi

I want to listen to Oracle's DBMS_ALERTs in Delphi XE6.
Is it possible to do that using ADO connection? 
Is it possible to do that using any other free components to connect to Oracle?

Currently we are using ODAC trial version, but Im looking for a free alternative.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't you have FireDAC in your Delphi distribution ? If so, use its `TADEventAlerter`.

Comment: I don't have FireDAC in my distribution, it comes with XE 7. Thank you anyway, you helped me a lot.